# Will conflicts arise between larger and smaller files in CRON job?

Tags: cron

I have set a cron job for a file for every 6 hours. The file may run for  4hours. 
If i set cron for another file , will it affect the previous one which may run for 4hours?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the job is not working on same resources, it wont conflict even if it's running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The cron daemon doesn't check to see if anything else by the same name is running, if that is what you mean, so cron will not care. However, if your script creates temporary files, for example, without using helper-tools like "mktemp" they could conflict with each other - so that will depend how well written your script is.